# Rails: bundler/runtime.rb:in `block in setup': You have already activated activesupport

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

After bundle update (Deploy app), i had this problem at bottom,
I'm use rbenv and CentOS on Deploy Server.

And I have other project running whiteout problems.

I'm tried to run "bundle exec" and "bundle exec rails s" and "bundle exec puma" but the problem stay.

Update 1: "bundle install --binstubs" running fine but not solved the problem.

Update 2: "In your deployed env, delete Gemfile.lock file and do bundle install that would fix your install" not worked.

Uptade 3: Child problem: [Rails: rubygems/dependency.rb:318:in `to_specs': Could not find 'activesupport'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35927463/rails-rubygems-dependency-rb318in-to-specs-could-not-find-activesupport)

Update 4: "You can try to update the version of activesupport that your application is using to resolve this." not worked.

Update 5: After rollback the project to old git hash the problem not occurred, but at last commit  the problem still.

```
Looks like your app's ./bin/rails is a stub that was generated by Bundler.

In Rails 4, your app's bin/ directory contains executables that are versioned
like any other source code, rather than stubs that are generated on demand.

Here's how to upgrade:

  bundle config --delete bin    # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
  rake rails:update:bin         # Use the new Rails 4 executables
  git add bin                   # Add bin/ to source control

You may need to remove bin/ from your .gitignore as well.

When you install a gem whose executable you want to use in your app,
generate it and add it to source control:

  bundle binstubs some-gem-name
  git add bin/new-executable

WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      json (>= 1.7.7, ~> 1.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      rack (>= 1.0, ~> 1.6)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1.0.5, ~> 1.0)
      thor (< 2.0, >= 0.18.1)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
/home/rails/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup': You have already activated activesupport 4.2.1, but your Gemfile requires activesupport 4.2.0. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /home/rails/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
    from /home/rails/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:92:in `setup'
    from /home/rails/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rails/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from /home/rails/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/rails/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
    from /var/www/html/zadmin/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rails/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:119:in `require'
    from /home/rails/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:119:in `require'
    from /home/rails/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:44:in `block in exec_app_rails'
    from /home/rails/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:34:in `loop'
    from /home/rails/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:34:in `exec_app_rails'
    from /home/rails/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/cli.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rails/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:67:in `require'
    from /home/rails/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:67:in `require'
    from /home/rails/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rails/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/rails:23:in `load'
    from /home/rails/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

Thanks!

Comment: what will happen if you do `$ bundle update` after deleting Gemlock.file?

Comment: Steps: https://gist.github.com/wellington1993/cc7837e488df4c0e7ebd

Comment: have you tried to uninstall & reinstall it again "gem uninstall activesupport" , follwed by bundle install ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update the version of `activesupport` that your application is using to resolve this.

It sounds like your system has `activesupport` `v4.2.1` while your `Gemfile.lock` specifies `v4.2.0`. To update the version of `activesupport` that your `Gemfile.lock` is specifying, try running the following:

```
bundle update activesupport
```

Additionally, you can try to delete your system `activesupport` gem via `gem uninstall activesupport` and then reinstall it via `bundle install`.

Comment: Thanks but not work -> After reinstall: Could not find 'activesupport' (= 4.2.1) among 736 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError) But successful installed: Bundle complete! 250 Gemfile dependencies, 417 gems now installed.